# Play Framework 2.4.1 One form with two buttons. Which button was pressed? And how do I get the input data?

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm afraid I'm lost. Using Play Framework 2.4.1 with Scala. In my form I have two buttons:

```
@form(routes.Orders.handle(order.id)) {
  @helper.textarea(field = userForm("name"), 'disabled -> "disabled")
  @helper.checkbox(field = userForm("next"), 'class -> "largerCheckbox")

  <button type="submit" name="action" value="one">Edit order</button>
  <button type="submit" name="action" value="two">Remove order</button>
}
```

The controller:

```
  def handle(id: Long) = Action { implicit request =>

  val userData = userForm.bindFromRequest.get

  request.body.asFormUrlEncoded.get("action").headOption match {
    case Some("one") => Ok("Clicked edit ")
    case Some("two") => Ok("Clicked remove")
    case _ => BadRequest("This action is not allowed")
  }
}
```

userForm.bindFromRequest.get throws in exception:

```
[NoSuchElementException: None.get]
```

How can I now differentiate in the controller which button has been pressed and also read in the user data?

UPDATE:

I have found a solution. Solution is perhaps saying too much, let's call it a terrible workaround:

```
val result = Try {request.body.asFormUrlEncoded.get("next").headOption}

val next = result match {
  case Success(value) => true
  case Failure(exception) => false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The name property can't be the same. Rename them to:

```
  <button type="submit" name="action1" value="one">Edit order</button>
  <button type="submit" name="action2" value="two">Remove order</button>
```